# Using Linq to loop through all controls only get the first control

Tags: c#, linq

I have a form with 5 text boxes and a button, I want to check all these text boxes for empty or null user input.
Using this simple method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (verifyUI() == true)
                MessageBox.Show("user input for all textboxes was correct!");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("user input for all textboxes was missing!");
        }

        private bool verifyUI()
        {
            bool userInputOk = false;
            foreach (Control cTxt in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cTxt.Text) || cTxt.Text == "")
                {
                    userInputOk = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    userInputOk = true;
                }
            }
            return userInputOk;
        }
    }
```

When I enter a value in text box 1 ,  the method is checking only the first text box and returning true, and ignoring all other text boxes.

I am sure something is wrong in the logic of the method which I am using.

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cTxt.Text)` already covers `cTxt.Text = ""`

Comment: Have you seen what `Controls` returns? Have you checked if the `TextBox`es you're looking for are in that collection? Maybe if they are nested within another `control` (like a `Panel`) only the parent comes out in that list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you want to know if *any* input is wrong (or *all* the input is correct):

```
  private bool verifyUI() {
    return !Controls
      .OfType<TextBox>() 
      .Any(cTxt => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cTxt.Text));
  }
```

or (equivalent `All()` implementation)

```
  private bool verifyUI() {
    return Controls
      .OfType<TextBox>() 
      .All(cTxt => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cTxt.Text));
  }
```

In your current code you constantly *re-write* `userInputOk` and so return the *last* value

Comment: thanks for illustration, can i ask you what is the difference between using any or all if i want to check all controls?

Comment: @Ashraf Abusada: technically no difference, just a way of thinking: user input is correct one if there're no wrong values found (`Any`); or user input is correct one if each value is correct (`All`)

Comment: I prefer the latter using `.All()` because it more directly expresses the intention.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: it's just a way of thinking: I, personally, prefer `Any` - the input is OK if you can't find *any* counter example.

Comment: True; either way, there's an annoying `!` in the logic. :) Thinking about it, I'd probably call the method `verificationFailed()` and then  get rid of the `!` (either one) and then the call site would probably look like `if (verificationFailed() { ... handle failure ... }` - as it is, `if (verifyUI() == true)` reads badly. Anyway, that's the OP's problem, not yours!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use the `All` method:

```
private bool verifyUI()
{
    return Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(tb => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text));
}
```

You could also invert the logic and use the `Any` method as well. I prefer `All` in this case simply because it conveys the intention better and makes the logic more clear for the next person.

Answer (score 2):

I think just for checking whether any textbox is not filled. following code is enough.

```
        private bool verifyUI()
        {
            bool alluserInputsOk = true;
            foreach (Control cTxt in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cTxt.Text))
                {
                    userInputOk = false;
                    break;
                }                   
            }
            return userInputOk;
        }
```

or You can use .any() method with your list

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually only checking whether the last control in the list is blank or not, since that's where your iteration ends.

Comment: Why iteration ends?

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks only the last textbox it finds. Try this `All()` statement instead:

```
bool userInputOk = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                           .All(tb => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text));
```

*Note* that `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is `true` for `string.Empty`, too. So you don't need that extra check for `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's probably looping though all controls, but only returning the result of the *last* one, since you set the value of `userInputOk` *back* to true if the control has valid text.  So the end result is the result for the *last* control.  Now it's possible that `textBox1` is the *last* control in the collection, depending on how they were added. You can either just remove the `else` block, which will flag `userInputOk` *only* if a control has an invalid value, or use Linq:

```
 bool userInputOk = 
          !Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                   .Any(cTxt => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cTxt.Text))
```